# share class library to other solution but readonly asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, class-library

hi i have to 2 solutions this is the first one(ProjectB)

[image]

my goal is to reference the ProjectB.Core to my other solution (ProjectA) but it needs to be read only or visible false

[image]

i successfully referenced it using add existing project but i can edit the code in projectA

Comment: Then do not add the project to the solution. just reference the ProjectB.Core dll from its output directory (usually the bin directory) from project A.

Comment: i need a solution that whenever i change some code to projectB.Core it will automatically reflected in projectA

Comment: not without having the other project as part of the solution. So it is either one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a post-build event in project properties to copy your library DLL to a folder where your other solution can reference it. Play with `xcopy` command.